# How to get the filename along with filecontent

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following 3 javascript routines:

```
function readFile(file, onLoadCallback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```
function processfile(filename, filecontent) {
    //finish working here
    PageMethods.setFile(filename, filecontent);
}
```

```
$('#div').on(
    'drop',
    function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                    readFile(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i], function (e2) {
                        processfile('', e2.target.result); // how to set the actual filename as the first parameter?
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

First I call a drop function which loops through the dropped files and get the content in a callback routine. And finally processfile to c# - but I cant send the filename to the function processfile.

So therefore I ask how to send the filename to that routine from the callback? Everything seems to work fine - except for the filename :-(

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the file itself:

```js
function readFile(file, onLoadCallback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = function () {
    onLoadCallback(file.name, reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```js
// ...
for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
  var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
  
  readFile(file, function (filename, content) {
    processfile(filename, content);
  });
}
// ...
```